# How to delete selected rows from a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, row

I have a `DataGridView` and a `Button`. If rows are selected I want to delete them by clicking the button. I tried a couple of commands like `RemoveAt`, `SelectedRows` etc., but nothing did work. How can I solve that?

I tried something like:

```cs
if (dataGridView2.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
{
    DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection rows = dataGridView2.SelectedRows;
    dataGridView2.Rows.RemoveAt(rows);
}
```

but the RemoveAt method does only accept integers. Before I tried it with Selected Cells but then he delets all rows because there is always a cell selected.

Comment: Yes - that is what I mean. Sorry for that

Comment: Please show what you have tried even if it didn't work. Then we know the problem and can help to fix it.

Comment: Note that if you have populated the grid using a datasource, you might want to update that source and grid will automatically update

Comment: These links might help you.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976348/delete-selected-row-in-datagridview-and-also-delete-row-in-database
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21038006/how-to-delete-selected-row-from-datagridview-and-database-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you just want to remove the selected rows from the `DataGridView` this should do it:

```cs
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in yourDataGridView.SelectedRows)
{
    yourDataGridView.Rows.RemoveAt(row.Index);
}
```

Your code didn't work because you've used `RemoveAt(rows)` but `RemoveAt` accepts only the index of the row which you want to remove. You are passing a `DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection` to it. You can get the index of a row  via [`DataGridViewRow.Index`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewband.index(v=vs.110).aspx) as shown above.

Comment: You may want to add a remark why this works without thowing an 'can't modify the iterated collection'..

Comment: @TaW: I guess that `SelectedRows` creates a new, separate collection that can modify `DataGridView.Rows`  during enumeration because it is not linked with it. **Edit** Confirmed: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridView.cs,37d6f20ebb9d623e

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for digging that up. [ListView](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ListView.cs) does the same. OTOH, it looks to me, as if [ListBox](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ListBox.cs) does the same as well but won't let you enumerate the collection and modify it..

Comment: @TaW: but you could use the `ListView.SelectedIndices`-collection, couldn't you?

Answer (score 2):

if you are using a list of model, following code could help:

```cs
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridViewX.SelectedRows)
{
    var val = (int)row.Cells[0].Value;
    Products.Remove(Products.Find(d => d.ProductId == val));
}
dataGridViewX.DataSource = null;
dataGridViewX.DataSource = Products;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can programmatically find what row you are trying to select:

```
dataGridViewX.Rows[0].Selected = true;
```

then delete the selected row:

```
dataGridViewX.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridViewX.SelectedRows[0].Index);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this, hope it's help

**1.** To enable delete , set the AutoGenerateDeleteButton to true and specify the delete command in the SqlDataSource.

```
 DeleteCommand="DELETE From [stores] WHERE [stor_id] = @stor_id"
```

**2.** Here we are trying to display a confirmation message before deleting the specified row. In order to doing this we have to write a small Javascript code for display confirmation message.

```
 function isDelete()
  {
    return confirm("Do you want to delete this row ?");
  }
```

**3.** We have to call this Javascript function on OnClientClick event of the delete LinkButton.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="DeleteBtn" runat="server" CommandName="Delete"
OnClientClick="return isDelete();">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
```

**4.** The follwoing ASP.NET program shows how to delete a row from Gridview and display a confirmation message before deleting the specified row.

**Default.aspx /// page**

```
![<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function isDelete()
        {
            return confirm("Do you want to delete this row ?");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    AllowSorting="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AllowPaging="True" DataKeyNames="stor_id" >
        <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField ReadOnly="True" HeaderText="stor_id"
        DataField="stor_id" SortExpression="stor_id"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="stor_name" DataField="stor_name"
        SortExpression="stor_name"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="stor_address" DataField="stor_address"
        SortExpression="stor_address"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="city" DataField="city"
        SortExpression="city"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="state" DataField="state"
        SortExpression="state"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="zip" DataField="zip"
        SortExpression="zip"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="DeleteBtn" runat="server" CommandName="Delete"
                OnClientClick="return isDelete();">Delete
                </asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <div>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SQLDbConnection %>"
    SelectCommand="select * from stores"
    DeleteCommand="DELETE From \[stores\] WHERE \[stor_id\] = @stor_id" >
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="stor_id" Type="String" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>]
```

**Here is the picture**

[image: Check this picture it's might help you]

Comment: this is a winforms question, not webforms

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there - try the following code-snippet

```cs
if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0) {
    DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection row = dataGridView1.SelectedRows;
    // taking the index of the selected rows and removing/
    dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index);
}
else {  //optional    
    MessageBox.Show("Please select a row");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i cam across this , and did not find the correct answer , when you delete a row , if this row is the first in collection , all other rows indices will be changed , and you may delete other rows.so you have to loop till the selecteditems count is equal to zero. or you may miss other selected rows.

Here is my method:

```cs
while (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
    dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index);
```

Comment: For loop should be used instead of while 
 for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count;i++ )

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like below

```cs
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dgv1.SelectedRows)
{
    dgv1.Rows.Remove(row);
}
```